# Using the strip function to strip integer at the ends of a string

Tags: python, string

I want to strip `0` from a given string.
The string contains either `1` or `0`. I want to strip the zeroes if they appear at the ends.

I know i can do this using if condition, but i want to know if there is any function made to do this efficiently than using if-else.

Example-

String = `0100010101010`

Output = `10001010101`

Also, i don't think using regex is any more efficient, complexity wise.

Comment: does this work `x.strip('0')`?

Comment: No, my first step was to do this. But strip isn't doing it.

Comment: @droid_31 Why strip isn't doing it?

Comment: @Ch3steR nope, this is also not working.

Comment: @Ch3steR I guess strip is just for stripping out the blank spaces.

Comment: is your input an string or an interger? if it's an integer, then you need to convert to to str first and then back to int: `int(str(x).strip('0'))`

Comment: Nah man, I am using  a string, i also verified it by printing s.type().

Comment: show us your code and the expected output. `strip()` should work without issues.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually i forgot to assign the output to s after stripping. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for the string `s`:

```
s = s.strip("0")
```

Make sure `s` is a string and not a number.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually i forgot to assign the output to s after stripping.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = "0100010101010"
print(s.lstrip("0").rstrip("0"))
'10001010101'
```

Comment: sorry, not working.

Comment: Is this a string you're working with?

Comment: Yes, it is a string.

Comment: So it has to work, if the string is the same as the one in your question.

Comment: @baduker I think he didn't store the resulting string since the changes made by `strip` won't be reflected in `s`

Comment: s = "0100010101010"
s = s.strip("0")
print(s)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually i forgot to assign the output to s after stripping.

Comment: That should do it he doesn't reassign s so it creates a new string and not changing the original one

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this , it will work

```
s = str(s).strip("0")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually i forgot to assign the output to s after stripping.

Comment: happy to help. It happens :)